# Difference between "almost uniformly convergent" and "almost uniformly Cauchy"?

Tags: measure-theory

In Bartle's book "The Elements of Integration", the definitions of almost uniformly convergent and uniformly Cauchy are very similar, I can't tell the difference between them.

Quote: A sequence $(f_n)$ of measurable functions is said to be **almost uniformly convergent** to a measurable function $f$ if for each $\delta>0$ there is a set $E_\delta$ in $\mathbf{X}$ with $\mu(E_\delta)<\delta$ such that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $X\setminus E_\delta$.

The sequence $(f_n)$ is said to be an **almost uniformly Cauchy sequence** if for every $\delta>0$ there exists a set $E_\delta$ in $\mathbf{X}$ with $\mu(E_\delta)<\delta$ such that $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent on $X\setminus E_\delta$.

What is the difference between the two definitions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference that the first specifies the function that it converges to, while the second does not.  The second leaves open the possibility that the limit is not measurable (but in fact you can prove that it is).

Comment: Are the two notions equivalent?

Comment: They are equivalent. Lemma 7.10 from Bartle proves they are the same.